# Different equation results from typing number and =cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope you can help.
I am compiling a sheet that runs a set of equations at the end of the row. To make things easier, I am using data from another sheet to autopopulate my formula's.
The problem I am finding is I get different results when using =cell address vs typing in the number directly. The number is 0.7 and is only to 1 decimal place. Even if I "ctrl C" the data into the cell, it produces the same answer as using the =.

It's left me a bit stumped as to why.
Can anyone shed some light as to what is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the data on the different sheet is not actually 0.7.

Comment: Make sure both cells have the same formatting.

Comment: Thanks, yes both cells have the same formatting. It would seem that the data on the sheet is different to what is copied over, but there is nothing visible to indicate that. The cell that's copied shows 8.2 when 0.7 is shown in the copied cell. Strange one.